# How do I know if AVAudioPlayer is using a file

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, nsfilemanager

I'd like to know if there is any instance of `AVAudioPlayer` using a file or if I can delete it.

Right now I'm using `- [NSFileManager isDeletableFileAtPath:]` but I'm not sure if I can trust it or if the player may be using the file and will crash when I delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if the `AVAudioPlayer` object's `data` or `url` variable is nil. Don't know which one you're using but could be what you want.

Comment: I don't want to have to depend on having a pointer to an instance. There may be third party players to which I don't have access to.